# AWS kinesis video streams (KVS) Multi-peer

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to use Amazon's Video Signaling service to create a multi-user video chat system. It appears as if the only supported topology is One-to-Many.  Does KVS support Many-to-Many?

i.e. One WebRTC session can feed multiple peers, but I can't mesh them so everyone could communicate with everyone.

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently support the mesh scenario with the signaling service out of the box. This is something we are looking at to support out-of-the-box but currently, there needs to be some solution engineering by enabling a higher-order coordinator.